# Replacing/removing square brackets in a string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, scripting

I have the following text in a file:

```
Names of students
[Name:Anna]
[Name:Bob]
[Name:Carla]
[Name:Daniel]
[ThisShouldNotBeBeRemoved]
End of all names
Blablabla
```

I want to remove all lines of the text file where there is an occurrence of the string in the format of [Name:xxx], xxx being a name as a string of any length and consisting of any characters.

I have tried the following, but it wasn't successful:

```
$ sed '/\[Name:*\]/d' file > new-file
```

Is there any other way I could approach this?

Comment: you just missed `.`, it should be `sed '/\[Name:.*\]/d'`... perhaps you were thinking in terms of glob instead of regex?

Answer (score 3):

I would use `grep` with `-v`

> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is specified by POSIX.)

```
grep -v "\[Name:"
```

Comment: use single quotes unless you need shell interpretation... `grep -v '\[Name:'`

Comment: @schorsch312 : Since we don't need any regexp metacharacters, `grep -vF '[Name:'` would be simpler. No need to escape the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.*` not just `*` ...

```
sed '/\[Name:.*\]/d' file > new-file
```

`*` on it's own is meaningless in this particular circumstance. Adding `.` before it signifies "match any character zero or more times" — which I think is what you're wanting to do.

If you wanted to do an ***in-place*** edit to the original file without re-directing to a new one:

Linux:

```
sed -i '/\[Name:.*\]/d' file
```

macOS:

```
sed -i '' '/\[Name:.*\]/d' file
```

<sub>* **note - this overwrites the original file.**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```
sed  '/\[Name:[[:alpha:]]+\]/d' file
 Names of students
[ThisShouldNotBeBeRemoved]
End of all names
Blablabla
```

Comment: You don't need regular expressions capable `sed` for this, can done `POSIX`-ly `sed`

Answer (score 0):

You missed out something,

```
sed '/\[Name:.*\]/d' file > new-file
```

This would remove your lines that match.

```
.*  This matches any character zero or more than once.
```

Answer (score 0):

OR if you don't want to create new file then try this,

sed -i '/[Name:.*]/d' file